# More than 1 linked list - Adding elements

Tags: c, list, pointers

I need to make a program that has (at most) 50 linked lists. Basically, my program generates some messages and based on a indicator that comes in the front of my string, I need to put the message in the right linked list.

I don't know if it is clear enough but I will try to show part of my code (the important part). The function I made to add a new element (on the top) of the linked list is the following:

```
void InsertLL (News p, char M[]) {
    char * text = malloc(strlen(M)+1);
    strcpy(text, M);
    News s,t;
    t = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    t-> Text = text;
    s = p;
    p = t;
    p-> next = s;
 }
```

My struct List (the type of the elements of my lists) contains a char pointer (called text) and a pointer to the next element of the list.

Simulating my program, suppose that I received a message that needs to be put in the linked list where the begin is pointed by the pointer p[0]. So I create a new element (forget the case that the list is empty, I already made this one) and add in the top of my list using the function I've shown.
Now, suppose that I received another message that needs to be put in the next pointer p[1]. If I print p[0] -> Text, I get the text of p[1]->Text.

I mean, if I add a new element in the list pointed by p[i], all the previous `texts p[i] -> Texts` gets the new text of this new element. I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

I don't know if it is enough to help me, if more information is needed, just tell me.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand that is the real problem.

Comment: Is your intent a "stack-like" list (where new elements always appear at the front) or a "queue-like" list (where new elements are always appended to the end, and the front is only set on first-insertion)? It makes a *big* difference in the algorithm. What you have here at least *appears* to be stack-like, but I don't think that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is you are not maintaining the list of nodes. you are overwriting the same node again and again.

Algo:

1. If no node then create one.
2. If nodes are present then navigate to end node.(You can use tail
   pointer for quicker access).
3. Append the node at the end.

Creating Node:

- Declare a node type pointer.
- Allocate memory to it.
- Update the content of the node.
- Set the next pointer of the node to null.
- Add this node to end of the list.

ex. inserting node 3 in the list of node 1 and node 2.

[image: Link list demo]

This is the general approach that you can use

```
typedef struct node{
    int val;   //you can use your text here
    struct node* next;
    }NODE;

struct node* head=0;

int addNode(int v){
    if(head==0){                              //checking for empty node.
        struct node* n=malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        n->val=v;
        head=n;
    }
    else{
        struct node* temp=head;
        while(temp->next != 0)    //Navigating till end
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        struct node* n=malloc(sizeof(NODE)); //allocating memory
        n->val=v;            //you need to use strcpy for string here.                         
        temp->next=n;       //adjusting pointers
        n->next=0;
    }
}
```

You can check this demo created by me for Double linked List http://ideone.com/s6TtUX

Comment: @user2768645 Show me your struct.

Comment: struct List { 
 char * Text; 
 News next;
} ; News is struct List *)

Comment: why if I defined News as struct List *? I made typedef struct List * News

Comment: Hmm. Then you need to maintain the list of nodes only. Check my prog. it's easy.

Comment: By the way, the problem persists even using News * next

Comment: I will check it again and try to do something like it. I talk with you again if it not works. Thanks

Comment: Does your program insert the element at the end of the list?

Comment: Yes! this code insert at end. For other functions you can refer to my link.

Comment: Great example @Arpit! will be useful to others